# Vue prop being mutated along with the data property so I can't reset the form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component that is passed an object. The object has a property that is an array of further objects.

I've created a form to edit the object and it's sub-components. The sub-component has it's own set of form controls that add to the parent form used to submit data back to the server.

I'm having trouble resetting the sub component data on clicking the reset button. It seems somehow the `storedModel` and `storedData` props being passed to each vue component are being mutated.

When I click reset the reset function in the child component is successfully triggered but the `storedData` property has been changed along with the form select input so the data is not reset to its original state.

If I console log the `storedData` property in the child component as well as the `form. sub_component_data` in the parent component I see that both have been mutated.
The `form.name` in the parent component is successfully reset to its original value as I would expect.

I've tried using `v-model` on the sub component with the necessary `model` property and event configuration instead of passing the data through as a prop but the reset still doesn't work.

Below is a simplification of my components. Any ideas?

Parent Component:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input id="name" name="name" v-model="form.name">
        <sub-componenet ref="subComponent" :stored-data="form.sub_component_data"></sub-component>
        <button type="button" @click="onReset">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            storedModel: {
                type: Array|Object,
                default: null
            }
        },

        data () {
            return {
                form: {
                    name: this.storedModel ? this.storedModel.name : '',
                    sub_component_data: this.storedModel ? this.storedModel.sub_component_data : [],
                },
                show: true,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onReset: function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Reset form values
                this.form.name = this.storedModel ? this.storedModel.name : '';
                this.form.sub_component_data = this.storedModel ? this.storedModel.sub_component_data : []

                console.log(
                    this.form.contracts
                );

                this.$refs['subComponent'].reset();

                // Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state
                this.show = false;
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.show = true;
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Sub Data Option</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(datum, index) in data" :key="index">
                    <td>
                        <b-form-select
                            :id="'sub-data-option' + index"
                            :name="'sub_data[' + index + '][option]'"
                            v-model="datum.option_id"
                            :options="options"
                            class="form-control"
                        ></b-form-select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            storedData: {
                type: Array|Object,
                default: function() {return []}
            }
        },

        data () {
            return {
                data: this.storedData ? this.storedData : [],
                options: [
                    {
                        value: null,
                        text: '-- Select Option --',
                        selected: true,
                        disabled: true
                    },
                    {
                        value: 1,
                        text: 'Option 1',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 2,
                        text: 'Option 2',
                    },
                ],
            }
        },

        methods: {
            reset: function () {
                // Reset form values
                this.data = this.storedData ? this.storedData : [];
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try `this.storedModel.sub_component_data.slice()` otherwise `this.form.sub_component_data` is the same array as `this.storedModel.sub_component_data`

Comment: Interesting, thanks @JaromandaX I'll give that a try. I would have thought that setting a data property to the value of a prop should always be done by value as the prop itself shouldn't be directly mutated?

Comment: [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow):  *Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.*

Comment: @JonWhite - as per comment above - the way you've assigned to `this.form.sub_component_data` means any change to the items in `this.form.sub_component_data` would necessarily change `this.storedModel.sub_component_data`

Comment: Thanks for the comments here. I see you're both right, the issue is that the property is being assigned by reference. I'm still having trouble as I can't work out how to pass or assign by value. @JaromandaX suggested `this.storedModel.sub_component_data.slice()` but that hasn't done it. I might try a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.storedModel.sub_component_data))`

Comment: Still this feels a little bit wrong in general. I'm wondering if I've made a fundamental mistake in the way I've designed these components. I feel like I should have used `v-model` to bind the data to the sub component. But I did try that and had the same problem... Maybe I should have put my `v-for` on the subcomponent and passed a single data item to each allowing the parent to handle the set of data. I'll have a go at it again later and see what comes out best.